# Reconfigure pfSense to use wifi/eth bridge instead of internal Ethernet interface

Tags: pfsense

I am using pfSense as an Internet router. So far I have not used the wifi adapter (it is present but disabled). I only use one of the Ethernet ports for the internal interface. For wifi I have a separate access point.

Now I would like to use the built-in wifi adapter in my pfSense box. (I am aware it is discouraged, but I believe none of the arguments against that are relevant for my use case.)

Outline of what I have in mind:

- Configure the wifi adapter as an access point, but with no IP config of its own – DONE
- Configure a bridge for both internal interfaces (eth and wifi) and create a new interface for it – DONE
- Set system tunables to filter bridge traffic at the bridge, not its member interfaces – DONE
- Move (or copy) IP config and rules from the internal eth interface to the bridge
- Add a rule for the bridge so that traffic can pass between eth and wifi

I got stuck at the fourth step: when I try to assign an IP address from my subnet to the bridge, I get an error because the address or range overlaps with that on the eth interface – which I eventuelly intend to remove, but not until I have the bridge interface up and working.

How can I move the IP config (and possibly also the rules) to a bridge interface from one of its members? (Also, there’s the automatic anti-lockout rule, which cannot be edited: how can I tell pfSense that this should go on the bridge, not one of its member interfaces?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a bridge as the internal interface is a somewhat advanced thing to set up, and best done while initially setting up the system (as it is easier to go back if something goes wrong), though it can be done afterwards as well.

Word of caution here: make sure you have a backup of your system in case something goes wrong. At the least, export your configuration and save it. Better yet, create a full image of your disk so you can always go back to the exact same system configuration you had before.

I did the following steps on OPNsense; they should work with pfSense just as well. Steps are loosely based on the [official OPNsense docs](https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/how-tos/lan_bridge.html).

You will need one additional free (unassigned) Ethernet interface during the switchover. We are assuming your LAN interface is named `LAN` in Interface Assignments, which is the default name assigned during setup, though it can be changed at any time later.

In Interface Assignments, choose the unused Ethernet interface to be the `LAN` interface, and save. Unplug your Ethernet cable from the old LAN interface, and plug it into the temporary interface. Make sure you can still access the web GUI from your workstation.

Configure the bridge, making sure to add the former (and future) LAN port as a member interface. Add other ports to the bridge as needed.

You may need to go into System Tunables (OPNsense has them under System > Settings > Tunables) and set `net.link.bridge.pfil_bridge` to 1 and `net.link.bridge.pfil_member` to 0. This will cause pfSense/OPNsense to filter bridge traffic at the bridge interface, not at its member interfaces. (I have configured my system this way, but that may not be needed.)

Back in Interface Assignments, choose the new bridge to be the `LAN` interface. Unplug the LAN cable from the temporary port and plug it into any Ethernet port which is on your new LAN bridge.

You now have a bridge as your internal interface. This allows you, for example, to configure a wifi access point on your device and assign a single IP address to both the wifi and your internal Ethernet port.

Be aware that pfSense/OPNsense filters all traffic at the bridge interface. If you want to enable communication between different ports on your bridge (e.g. between machines on Ethernet and those connected to a wifi access point on the same bridge), you will need to add rules.

IMHO this is quite cumbersome; I have opened [issue 5604](https://github.com/opnsense/core/issues/5604) for OPNsense, in the hope that this will be easier in some future version.